# How to express the PCA principal components as a linear combination of input data?

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, linear, covariance-matrix, unsupervised-learning

In [this paper](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01965582/document) in equation 1 it shows that the principal component vectors are the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix and gives the following equation

$$\lambda_l\psi_l=C\psi_l$$
where $C$ is the covariance matrix.
Then it says that since eigenvectors lie in the span of data:

$$\psi_l = \frac{1}{\lambda_l}C\psi_l= \frac{1}{n\lambda_l}\sum_{i=1}^n\langle\mathbf{x}_i, \psi_l \rangle \mathbf{x}_i$$

I do not understand how the last equality has been obtained. Suppose $C = X^TX$, then one has
$$\psi_l = \frac{1}{\lambda_l}(X^TX)\psi_l=$$

which to me looks different from

$$\frac{1}{n\lambda_l}\sum_{i=1}^n\langle\mathbf{x}_i, \psi_l \rangle \mathbf{x}_i = \frac{1}{n\lambda_l}(\mathbf{x}_1^T \psi_l \mathbf{x}_1 + \mathbf{x}_2^T \psi_l \mathbf{x}_2+\cdots)$$

Can please someone explain this passage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're the same because:
$$X^TX\psi_l=\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{x}_1&\mathbf{x}_2&\dots&\mathbf{x}_n\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{x}_1^T\\\mathbf{x}_2^T\\\vdots\\\mathbf{x}_n^T\end{bmatrix}\psi_l=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{x}_i\mathbf{x}_i^T\right)\psi_l=\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{x}_i\underbrace{\mathbf{x}_i^T\psi_l}_{<\mathbf{x_i},\psi_l>}$$

Comment: what about the term $\frac{1}{n}$? Where does it come from?

Comment: Covariance matrix, $C$ is estimated as $\frac{1}{n}X^TX$, not $X^TX$ (or sometimes $\frac{1}{n-1}$). Note that $X$ should be mean-centered.

Comment: thanks a lot. Just a further clarification: with this representation of the covariance matrix the input data matrix has observations on the rows, while the columns are features right?

Comment: Yes, and the columns should be mean-centered.